# How to run NPM Command in Java code using ProcessBuilder

Tags: java, npm

My environment is mac.
I'm trying to run "npm ls" from my java code but it throws error messages.

My java code:

```
String npm = isWindows() ? "npm.cmd" : "npm";

System.out.println(rootStr);
Process process = new ProcessBuilder(npm, "ls").directory(new File(rootStr)).start();
```

Error Message:

```
Users/youngeun/Downloads/zenbot_unstable
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "npm" (in directory "/Users/youngeun/Downloads/zenbot_unstable"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at com.iotcube.scanner.nodejs.npm.NpmService.npmInfo(NpmService.java:26)
    at com.iotcube.scanner.IotcubescannerApplication.main(IotcubescannerApplication.java:174)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:247)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 2 more
```

But it seems to work perfectly in my terminal:

```
| ~/Downloads/zenbot_unstable @ Youngeunui-MacBook-Pro (youngeun) 
| => npm ls
zenbot4@4.1.0 /Users/youngeun/Downloads/zenbot_unstable
├─┬ @babel/core@7.2.2
│ ├─┬ @babel/code-frame@7.0.0
│ │ └─┬ @babel/highlight@7.0.0
│ │   ├── chalk@2.4.2 deduped
│ │   ├── esutils@2.0.2 deduped
│ │   └── js-tokens@4.0.0
│ ├─┬ @babel/generator@7.3.0
│ │ ├── @babel/types@7.3.0 deduped
│ │ ├── jsesc@2.5.2
│ │ ├── lodash@4.17.11 deduped
...
```

I've tried solutions from other stackoverflow pages but none of them seems to work...
I am so lost.. I would appreciate your help. thanks

Comment: Processes don't inherit system environment variables, so you need to know exactly where the `npm` binary is.

Answer (score 2):

Try providing full path to the `npm` executable:

```
String dir = "/Users/youngeun/Downloads/zenbot_unstable";
String npm = dir + "/npm";
Process p = new ProcessBuilder(npm, "ls")
                .director(new File(dir))
                .start();
p.waitFor();
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Now the error message doesn't show. Though, the process.waitFor(); returns 1 which means Failure. I don't know what's wrong..

Comment: Redirect the `Process` error output using `ProcessBuilder.redirectError()` or some other method. It should show the error message.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking something simple from NPM like downloading of packages and extraction it locally, or search for packages or something like that: there is alternative approach - use java native library to work with NPM registry: https://github.com/OrienteerBAP/JNPM